# Querying for all rows that have the pattern of a constant value in one field but different values in another field using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, query, select

In ArcGIS (ArcMap 10.8 or Pro 2.6) I have a table of 4000 buildings (rows). Each row/building belongs to one of fifty groups and thus has a group ID of 1-50 in the field GROUP_ID. Each row also has a GROUP_STATUS field which can have the value of "fully open" or "partly open".

Some groups have conflicting statuses. For example, there are multiple rows in Group_ID = 10, 14, or 40 which have values of both "partly open" and "fully open" in GROUP_STATUS. For these, and all other groups that have the same issue, I need to change the status to only "partly open". I need to find out for which GROUP_IDs this is the case so I can update the status accordingly.

Without doing a frequency table - only a selection or definition query - how do I identify all GROUP_IDs that have different values for GROUP_STATUS in the table?

I would like to find rows where GROUP_ID = a single value and GROUP_STATUS = more than one value across the rows, along the lines of "select by GROUP_ID where GROUP_ID is consistent but GROUP_ID is not consistent."

Comment: Is the data stored locally (e.g.shapefile, FGDB) or in an Enterprise Database? In the latter case it's probably easier to query the database directly.

Comment: It's possible to use a DA SearchCursor to build a dictionary in Python, then an UpdateCursor to adjust values, but using Summary Statistics is far easier.

Comment: @Berend: it's stored locally

Answer (score 1):

A frequency table is exactly what you need to use.

In the Summary Statistics tool, set

- Statistics Field to *group_status*
- Statistic Type to *COUNT*
- Case field to *group_id*

In the resulting table, select either records where COUNT_group_status = 1, or COUNT_group_status != 1

If you want, you could then join the Houses table to the Statistics table, ni order to select buildings directly.